MSO v:image and v:rect cannot have more than one instance
I am trying to create an HTML email. Some images break in Mircosoft Office so to combat that I do some mso specific stuff.
What I use is the following:
<!--[if mso]>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
        background="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png"
        width="100%" height="200" valign="top"
        style="background: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png') center / cover no-repeat #FFFFFF;">
    <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"
        style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 607pt; height: 150pt;"
        src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"
        style=" border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 607pt; height:150pt;">
        <v:fill opacity="0%" color="#FFFFFF" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    </td>
<![endif]-->

This works pretty well, however I am trying to use it in two different places, but with different images. For some reason when I try a second one, whichever is loaded first is the only one that works. The second one will not render but still take up space.
